# Implement `AsRef` and `Borrow` on `Cow`

Tags: rust

In the standard library, `Cow` implements `AsRef` and `Borrow` in different ways.

In `AsRef` it returns `self`:

```
impl<T: ?Sized + ToOwned> AsRef<T> for Cow<'_, T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T {
        self
    }
}
```

In `Borrow` it returns `&**self`:

```
impl<'a, B: ?Sized> Borrow<B> for Cow<'a, B>
where
    B: ToOwned,
    <B as ToOwned>::Owned: 'a,
{
    fn borrow(&self) -> &B {
        &**self
    }
}
```

Is this difference very important?

Comment: I feel like most linters would balk at the second implementation, suggesting replacing it with the first. I wonder if the `borrow` impl is older (Deref coercion in Rust has gotten smarter over time)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Both were committed at around the [same time](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blame/master/library/alloc/src/borrow.rs). Am I correct that the impl of `AsRef` and `Borrow` could be entirely the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a significant difference between the two, they could be swapped without any issue. The first uses an implicit deref coercion and the second uses an explicit dereference. Both are able to convert `&Cow<'_, T>` to `&T` because `Cow` implements `Deref`.

Comment: The second also has an additional lifetime constraint: `<B as ToOwned>::Owned: 'a`, which is missing in the first. What's the importance of this lifetime constraint? Does it make a difference?

Comment: That I'm not quite sure of. I'm struggling to construct a case where `B::Owned` could have a lifetime less than `'a`. There are places where lifetime constraints are implied (like `&'b &'a T` implies `'a: 'b`) so its probably redundant if the `AsRef` implementation has omitted it. Especially since the `Deref` implementation that it relies upon doesn't have that constraint either.